# Additional space within div

Tags: html, css

I'm a bit confused... 
Can anybody tell me, where this additional space above and below the "T" comes from?

"line-height" has exactly the same value as "font-size". I expected that the div should have the same height as the "T" itself...

Thanks!

[image: The T]

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<style type="text/css">
#container {
    font-size: 50px;
    background-color: lime;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">T</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's just vertical spacing/padding on the actual font itself. You can reduce the `line-height`.. http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/J2mRJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `line-height` is supposed to do : make a line high enough in order to be readable and to prevent lines from overlapping each others. `line-height` is calculated depending of `font-size` property. By default it's equal to `1.2em`.

Set a `font-size` of `50px` does not mean that all your characters will have a `50px` height. As the [spec says](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props):

> The font size corresponds to the em
>   square, a concept used in typography.
>   Note that certain glyphs may bleed
>   outside their em squares.

To understand em square : [wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_%28typography%29).

So the "margin" you got here is on the font itself, because 'T' character's height is not equal to 1em.

Have a look at [this documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/line-height). You will understand this property better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Your are absolutely right. If font-size: 50px really would mean that each character has a height of 50px a "a" should have the same height as a "T"...

Answer (score -1):

Basically this is a problem with font rendering as far as i know, But there's a really easy fix for it.

CSS

```
div {
    background-color: green;
    font-size: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10%;
    color: white;
    line-height: 1em; /* Normal Line Height */
    line-height: 0.8em; /* The One that Fixes the Problem */
}
```

HTML

```
<div>T</div>
```

And here's the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YoussefSH/V6nNq/), If you have any more questions just tell me.

Comment: There is no problem with font rendering. Not understanding something does not mean there is something wrong with it.

Comment: What i mean by font rendering is, It doesn't give it it's exact line height like programs (PS/IL, etc), I think my answer was very clear though by putting a lower value on the line-height that is lower than the font-size you fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Play around with setting the `height` of your `div` in addition to the `line-height` and `font-size`

Comment: Not a good solution, the only thing you'll get is that characters will  overlap the parent div and go outside.